# Twilio outbound call is not connecting as real phone call using php and also not showing hang up button on browser

Tags: php, twilio

I'm new in twilio and trying to implement it in my web application by using php sdk but when i call to destination phone no. (To Number) then it's only play a ringtone instead of real ring of phone (whatever we write into response code). I want to know that how i can connect with destination phone no. real way. I search a lot but don't get any suitable solution. One more thing how we can provide hang up button to disconnect a call.

I tried below code for voice outbound call

```
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from console.twilio.com
$sid = "ACdefc6a240fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "bceedc5daf3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

// Read TwiML at this URL when a call connects (hold music)
$call = $client->calls->create(
    $to_number,
    // Call this number
    $from_number,
    // From a valid Twilio number
    [
         "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
    ]
);

print_r($call);
```

I also try below code with  but still not connecting only received call on destination number and when pick the call from destination number then it's disconnected without any error message.

```
// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from console.twilio.com
$sid = "ACdefc6a240fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "bceedc5daf3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

// Read TwiML at this URL when a call connects (hold music)
$call = $client->calls->create(
    $to_number,
    // Call this number
    $from_number,
    // From a valid Twilio number
    [
         "twiml" => "<Dial><Number>".$to_number."</Number></Dial>"
    ]
);

print_r($call);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to configure your Twilio phone number's webhook to point to the PHP file that generates the TwiML response.

Keep in mind that Twilio's documentation and resources are valuable tools for addressing specific issues and understanding Twilio's functionality in depth.

If you continue experiencing issues, consider checking your TwiML, reviewing the logs in your Twilio account, and reaching out to Twilio's support if needed.

Comment: Do we need to set webhook in case of outbound call ?

Comment: you just cropped this from the bottom of a chatgpt response, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's start working with javascript and php. Got this link of twilio integration https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-php